# Bootstrap multiselect onselectAll only select those option with active status

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

Let say I have a list of options in the multi select box like below:

1. A (active)
2. B (active)
3. C (inactive)
4. D (inactive)
5. E (active)

What I want is that when the user click on select all, only the options with active status would be selected. Can anyone just give me the idea on how to do this using bootstrap multiselect plugin.Thanks.

Comment: can you share some code that you have tried ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq I have no idea how to start with, so can I get any idea from you? FYI, I am using bootstrap multiselect plugin.